# I'm trying to write a general function for adding/multiplying terms in a sequence

Tags: python, sequence, higher-order-functions

I'm trying to write a function with 4 arguments in python

```
def sequence(operation, start, n, term):
```

where operation is a function, start is the beginning number of the sequence, and n is th last number of the sequence, term is function that manipulates the terms in the sequence.

For example

```
>>> sequence(add, 2, 10, square)
```

would return the summation of the square of 2, 3, 4, ..., 10

given that:

```
def square(x):
    return x * x
```

Comment: And...? Where's your problem?

Comment: Homework? Maybe some attempt on your own might be a good idea.

Comment: google for "python" with each of the following keywords "map", "reduce" and "range".

Comment: Or just read about each of those functions here: http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html

Comment: yup! i've tried using recognizing the patterns in summation and product in that it combines the next term with the preceding. However, I don't know how to use the arguments

Answer (score 2):

```
reduce(lambda a,b: a+b, map(square, range(2,11)))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def sequence(operation, start, n, term):
    return reduce(operation, map(term, range(start, n+1)))
```

The range function in Python is half-open ie. range(start, stop) returns a list of integers from start to stop-1. So, for example:

```
>>> range(2,10)
[2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

Therefore, to solve your problem you would need range(start, n+1).

To apply the function "term" to each integer in this range you would use the built-in function map eg:

```
>>> map(square,range(2,11))
[4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81, 100]
```

The final part of the function requires the built-in function reduce which takes as its arguments a function, an iterable and an optional initial value (which is not required in this instance).

reduce applies the given function to the first two elements of the iterable; it then applies the function to the result of the first calculation and the third element of the iterable and so on.

So, for example:

```
>>> from operator import add
>>> reduce(add, [4, 9, 16, 25])
```

... is equivalent to:

```
>>> add( add( add(4, 9), 16), 25)
```

... and:

```
>>> reduce(add, [4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81, 100])
```

... is equivalent to:

```
>>> add( add( add( add( add( add( add( add(4, 9), 16), 25), 36), 49), 64), 81), 100)
```

Comment: ``range(start, n+1)`` effectively creates an object, while ``xrange(start, n+1)`` creates an iterator that will drop the numbers one after the other on demand. Your solution would be improved writing ``reduce(operation, map(term, xrange(start, n+1)))`` . Similarly, ``map(...,...)`` creates also an object while ``imap(...,...)`` creates an iterator. With ``return reduce(operation, map(term, range(start, n+1)))``, your solution will be perfect and better than mine, because more general. I upvote

Answer (score 0):

You can define sequence in one-liner using [Python Built-in functions](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html) `range`, `reduce` and `map`.

Answer (score 0):

```
from operator import add,mul

def square(x):  return x * x


def sequence(oper,m,n,func):
    if oper not in (add,mul):
        return None
    return reduce(lambda a,b: oper(a,func(b)),
                  xrange(m,n+1),
                  0 if oper==add else 1)


print sequence(add, 3,4, square)
print sequence(mul,2,3,square)
print sequence('qq',10,110,square)
```

result

```
25
36
None
```